# adding 2checkout to impresspages

Tags: impresspages, 2checkout

Dear Impress Page users,
I need to know how to setup 2checkout as peyment option in my widget,

currently my ms-widget has Filter.php referring to plugin 'PayPalSubscription', 
I want the plugin to refer to '2Checkout'

I am not good in php, and I also wanted to ask if someone can provide the script, or let me know how I can edit the paypal script to use 2checkout.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about ImpressPages MultiSite? If yes, this plugin is not hardly bind to PayPal. You can install any kind of payment system and MultiSite will use it. Basically I would say have a look at PayPalSubscription plugin as example and create 2checkout plugin. But if you are not very good at PHP you can probably order this plugin to be built for you on ipmultisite.com support page.